# Debugging mvc web application using subdomains in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging, subdomain

If I want to use subdomains for images, stylesheets and javascripts on my website (like img.domain.com), how would you set it up in Visual Studio 2008 so I am able to debug the website on my local computer?

Is it possible ? and how ?

The webdev server always uses localhost:port, is there anyway to map etc. img.localhost:port to a specific folder in a project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and map and arbitrary domain name to 127.0.0.1 (i.e. localhost).  Then, set your debug action to open a custom URL.

*(edit in response to comments)*
If you need to have different directory structures, you'll need to complicate the setup a bit.  I'd try setting up IIS with a virtual directory pointed at the same content, especially if it's static (like images).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I dont understand how i can use this to make it possible to map static.localhost to the /content/ folder of my website, soo my urls can be static.localhost/img/mymimage.jpg like on the production server.

Comment: where the /img/ folder is a folder inside the /content/ folder.